# which web api testing framework can be used for testing api which supports c#, is open source, free and has no privacy and security concerns?

Tags: c#, frameworks

I need a web api testing framework, which supports writing the test scripts in c# and is free, not licensed and having no privacy and security issues for using all of its features.I need this for testing api's of a project

Comment: Asking for tools, libraries, tutorials, or off-site resources is off-topic in here

Comment: why not write unit tests to test your own APIs?

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to setup a framework to test an WebAPI, you are going to need it if you are going to use it in your project.

To test a WebAPI I would recommend you a [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) witch is very useful for WebAPI testing.

---

And if you are going to use it in your project you can use an System.Net.Http and [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) this is also works for .NET Core as well. This is most comfortable option at a current moment.

There is also a few options as [WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=netframework-4.8) witch is a require more code to write to actually use it, and also a little bit harder to use with async.

Comment: Yes,but I need a framework and have to include it in the project.It should be tester perspective.I have said not to use Postman.

Comment: @Ankita Then I would recommend to use HttpClient this is a part of .NET Framework and also a part of .NET Core so it will do the job for you. Just follow the links this is official Microsoft Documentation witch you can read to understand how to use it.